# Azure databricks %run magic command unable to find file path

Tags: runtime-error, databricks, azure-databricks, file-not-found, magic-command

I have 2 notebooks under the root folder in my workspace. Calling one notebook from the other with %run magic cmd returns error saying file path not found. This is my command:

```
%run /Users/name@comp.com/notebookB $arg1=val1 $arg2=val2
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the solution, turns out the run command needs to be in a cell all by itself - no other code and no comments. I have seen some solutions online say that the cell should not contain any comments, but turns out it should not contain any other code either.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my life after a day of searching

Answer (score 0):

It's really better to use relative names instead of absolute (starting with `/`):

- If both notebooks are in the same folder, then you can refer to another using syntax `./notebook_name`
- If another is in the folder above, then use `../notebook_name`
- if another is in the subfolder, then use `subfolder/notebook_name`